# jQuery price Slider plugin issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

|----|----|----|----|----|

6     12   19   30   50  60

I want add this scale value to the [This jquery slider](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/)

i tried with all other example but this one not working with "step:1" i cannot understand this jqueries concept please help me to get rid of this issue

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
{
from: 0,
to: 60,
step: 6,
dimension: '',
scale: ['6', '12', '19', '30', '50', '60'],
limits: false
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but the second pointer shows wrong dimension while moving  you can check that one...
http://jsfiddle.net/sunith_123/pYUJS/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<input id="Slider5" type="slider" name="area" value="0;30" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
 jQuery("#Slider5").slider({ 

  from: 0,
  to: 60,
  dimension: '',
  scale: ['6', '12', '19', '30', '50', '60'],
  limits: false

})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYUJS/) here